# Merging PDF gives me UnsupportedDocumentException when using AWS Textract

Tags: pdf, merge, amazon-textract

I have 2 PDFs that can be analysed by AWS textract (textract.analyze_document). However, after using the python library fitz to merge two PDFs, the merged PDF cannot be anlayzed by AWS textract.

This is very puzzling and I am searching an altenative to fitz so that merged PDFs can be anlayzed by AWS textract.

I imagine that there could be other PDF libraries that would work.